# How can I convert a string to an int in c++ when I'm not using a standard string?

Tags: c++, string, int

I'm building my own string class and I'm trying to use this function to convert a numerical string to an integer:

```
int String::convertToInt() const {  
    int exp = length() - 1;
    int result = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < length(); ++i) {
        result += (charAt(i) - '0') * (10 ^ exp);
        --exp;
    }   
    return result;
}
```

Something isn't working right, but I can't pick out what it is. When I try to convert "49" to an int, it converts it to 134.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does atoi() function in C++ work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710091/how-does-atoi-function-in-c-work)

Comment: Have you looked at 'atoi' or 'strtol'/'strtoul'?

Answer (score 9):

`^` is XOR. I believe you're looking for `std::pow(10, exp)`.

Or even this:

```
int String::convertToInt() const {  
    int order = std::pow(10, length() - 1);
    int result = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < length(); ++i) {
        result += (charAt(i) - '0') * order;
        order /= 10;
    }   
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @MSalters Better now? I was typing the edit as you commented. Of course the canonical approach here is Horner (+1'd your answer for that), but I was trying to stick close to the OP's code.

Comment: The problem is that `std::pow` isn't exactly fast, it uses floating-point math. Similarly, integer division isn't that fast either. You'd be better off starting with `i=length()-1` and `order=1`, then doing `order *= 10` and `--i`.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to realize that `49` is `4 * 10 + 9`, and `493` similarly is `49 * 10 + 3`.

That is to say, the result is 10 times the first N-1 digits plus the last digit. You can write that as a loop or as a recursive function. Stack depth won't hurt you; after about 20 digits you'd overflow even a 64 bits result. So

```
int String::convertToInt() const {
    if (empty()) return 0; // Recursive functions better terminate.
    // TODO: negative numbers.  
    return 10 * convertToInt(substr(0, length()-1)) + (back() - '0');
}
```

or

```
int String::convertToInt() const {
    // TODO: negative numbers.  
    int result = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < length(); ++i) {
        result * = 10;
        result += (charAt(i) - '0');
    }   
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean... 493 is `(((4 * 10) + 9) * 10) + 3` (one digit at a time)

Comment: @Dave: That's also true. It just shows the first two steps in a single expression.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient approach would be:

```
// I know you said you are using something else
// but the same principle applies here
std::string s = "12345";

unsigned int result = 0;
unsigned int place = 1;
for (std::size_t i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i, place *= 10)
{
    result += (s[i] - '0') * place;
}
```

Basically, you start at the right-most character and work your way left.  Each character you move left, you multiply your `place` by 10 (very similar to how most of us learned to do addition growing up:  add your 1's ... add your 10's ... add your 100's ... etc.).  This also assumes that you already know the string contains nothing but numeric characters ('0'-'9').